# How to stretch components vertically so they are the same height as their 'sibling' lightning:layoutitem component/s?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am using the `lightning:layout` and `lightning:layoutItem` components to build a new lightning page. It is a basic layout with only two columns. I'd like the two columns to be the same height, but their height is currently governed by their individual content.

`lightning:layoutItem` has a 'flexibility' attribute which allows you to define the horizontal behaviour of these columns. Is there an equivalent for the vertical alignment of columns?

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="true" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="centre">
    <!--Header - Progress Indicator-->
    <lightning:layoutItem size="8"  flexibility="auto">
        <div class="slds-card" style="height:100%">
            <c:PlatformMessageFormProgressIndicator currentPage="{!v.currentPage}"/>
            Platform Message Actions (Save, Next, Previous, Cancel)
        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>   
    <!--Right Panel - Message Preview Window -->
    <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="horizontal-small" flexibility="auto">
        <div class="slds-card" style="height:100%">
        <c:PlatformMessageFormPreviewWindow messageType="{!v.messageType}" currentDateTimeString="{!v.currentDateTimeString}"/>
            </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **verticalAlign="stretch"** in **lightning:layout** and should have **lightning-layout-item** **flexibility="auto"**. Below is a sample code from Salesforce Documentation:-

```
<aura:component>
    <p>The layout items extend vertically to fill the container.</p>
    <div class="c-container">
        <lightning:layout verticalAlign="stretch" multipleRows="true" class="x-large">
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" class="custom-box">
                1
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" class="custom-box">
                2
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" class="custom-box">
                3
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" class="custom-box">
                4
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

You can have a detailed look here:- [Lightning Layout Vertical Align Stretch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layout/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleLayoutVerticalStretch)

Comment: +1 for the answer - this works.